# Find pattern that is present twice and allow <=2 mismatches on each

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I have a fastq file of 400,000 reads (so speed is important). In the sequences there are barcodes integrated that should be present twice. Given a barcode, I want to find the sequences that have the barcode present twice with <= 2 mismatches. So, with a barcode 'ATTCGACCGATAGG', I would like to retrieve all of the following sequences-

> TATCTTGTGGAAAGGACGAAACACCGAACACAAAGCATAGATGCGTTTAAGAGCTATGCTGGAAAACAGCATAGCAAGTTTAAATAAGGCTAGTCCGTTATCAACTTGAAAAAGTGGCACCGAGTCGGTGCTTTTTTT**ATTCGACCGATAGG**GGTGGCAGGGGAGGCCGAGGAGGAAGAAGGGGAGGTGGCAG**ATTCGACCGATAGG**TGGCGTAACTAGATCTTGAGACAAA
> TATCTTGTGGAAAGGACGAAACACCGGTCCGAGCAGAAGAAGAAGTTTAAGAGCTATGCTGGAAACAGCATAGCAAGTTTAAATAAGGCTAGTCCGTTATCAACTTGAAAAAGTGGCACCGAGTCGGTGCTTTTTTT**ATTCGACCGATAGG**GGTGGCAGGGGAGGCCGAGGAGGAAGAAGGGGAGGTGGCAG**ATTCGACCGATAGG**TGGCGTAACTAGATCTTGAGACAAA
> TATCTTGTGGAAAGGACGAAACACCGAGTCCGAGCAGAAGAAGAAGTTTAAGAGCTATGCTGGAAACAGCATAGCAAGTTTAAATAAGGCTAGTCCGTTATCAACTTGAAAAAGTGGCACCGAGTCGGTGCTTTTTTT**ATTCGACCGATAGG**GGTGGCAGGGGAGGCCGAGGAGGAAGAAGGGGAGGTGGCAG**ATTCGACCGATAGG**TGGCGTAACTAGATCTTGAGACAAA
> TATCTTGTGGAAAGGACGAAACACCGAGTCCGAGCAGAAGAAGAAGTTTAAGAGCTATGCTGGAAACAGCATAGCAAGTTTAAATAAGGCTAGTCCGTTATCAACTTGAAAAAGTGGCACCGAGTCGGTGCTTTTTTT**ATTCGACGATAGG**GGTGGCAGGGGAGGCCGAGGAGGAAGAAGGGGAGGTGGCAG**ATTCGACCGATAGG**TGGCGTAACTAGATCTTGAGACAAA

Note that the first barcode in the fourth sequence is short of one character. I have tried with biopython and regex but it's just too slow given I have 5k barcodes. I am wondering if there is a fast solution available in python or in something like grep, awk or anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I've used FlexBar (https://github.com/seqan/flexbar) for a similar task a couple of years ago - worth a look. You might get better/more up-to-date answers to this type of domain-specific question on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ e.g. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/collapse-cell-barcodes-distribution-within-1-hamming-distance

Comment: Did you try compiling the regex in python before running it on all the strings?

Comment: `agrep -2 ATTCGACCGATAGG file`

Comment: This has been asked and answered on this forum a few times. google it or search the archives.

Comment: None of them solves my problem. Please read my question carefully first. I am not a newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
 awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { fnd=0;subs=$i;while (match(subs,"ATTCGACCGATAGG")) { subs=substr(subs,RSTART+RLENGTH);if (RSTART>0) { fnd++;print fnd } } if (fnd <=2) { print $i } } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
 awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                           # Loop on each space delimited field
         fnd=0;                                         # Initialise fnd variable/counter
         subs=$i;                                       # Initialise substring variable
         while (match(subs,"ATTCGACCGATAGG")) { 
           subs=substr(subs,RSTART+RLENGTH);            # Check for multiple matches of "ATTCGACCGATAGG" in subs.
           if (RSTART>0) { 
              fnd++;                                    # Increment fnd if string found in subs
           } 
         } 
         if (fnd <=2) { 
            print $i                                    # If found twice or less than twice print the field
         }
        } 
       }' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I don't know awk that much, in which part of the code it its evaluating the <=2 mismatches allowed? I am assuming the fnd <= 2 checks if the pattern is present twice.

Comment: Yeah fnd represents the count of matches.

Comment: So, is there a way to allow <= mismatches with the barcode in awk?

Comment: The match function is matching the bar code and the fnd counts the number of matches in each string.